# How to force visual studio build fail after unit tests failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Currently, I am using Visual Studio 2012 and automate unit test execution after each build. However, what I would to do is fail the build if a single unit test fails . The following steps are what I want to do

1. Build the solution
2. When (1) succeed, run all unit tests automatically
3. When at step 2, if a unit test fails, make the build fail

I am able to do 1 and 2 ( which are out of the box), but don't know how for step 3. This is for local build

Comment: What for?  Saying the build failed like this is hiding what the actual problem is.  Are you trying to do Continuous Integration?

Comment: I am trying to stop developer from checkin code that has unit test broken. I dont worry about the actual problem because I have error window and I can see that , or I can the test window. That is not a concern for me

Comment: Have you looked at gated check-in builds on a build server?

Comment: No I dont want to do gated checkins. I want it to be simple

Comment: I'm guessing you'd need to add custom build task (I'm not sure if 2012 has any new feature) - e.g. like code weaving does the IL in after the compile (e.g. MS CCI). And e.g. [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724(v=vs.110).aspx) - you have the `DependOn` for build tasks so to kind of force your building to listen to your custom task. I don't have enough for an answer, just a tip.

Comment: The ability to do this would be useful. Using Git with TFS, there's no gated check-ins, so we only know our tests have failed if the build fails, when the code is already checked in.

Answer (score 2):

You can add Nunit or whatever framework execution as msbuild task in your project file. Here is an example:

http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/msbuild-and-nunit-a-simple-example/